# How do I use the wordpress has_term() function outside of functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pretty new to wordpress custom theme coding so excuse the silly question. I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy attached to it, and basically I want to only show specific posts on the front end that have a couple of specific taxonomy terms attached to them.

I've tried it like this (within a template.php file, not functions.php):

```
<?php

if ( have_posts() ) :

  while (have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if (has_term(array(
      'term1', //the first term i want posts to have
      'term2' // the second term i want the post to have -- only print the post on the front end if it has these two terms
    ), 'taxonomyname','posttypename')) {

      echo('it has the terms');
    ?>
  
  <div>
 <!-- this is where it would print out post specific stuff, the title, the content, etc -->
  </div>

    <?php
  } else {
    echo('has no relevant terms??');
  }
  endwhile;
    else : echo '<p> There are no posts. </p>';
  endif
  ?>
```

As you can imagine, it echos "has no relevant terms??" every time. I've been looking for hours but there's nothing informative or beginner friendly out there. The codex example hasn't really made it any easier to achieve what I want.

I will be so so grateful for any help. Thank you!

EDIT:

As the third parameter, I've tried the following:

- $post_id
- $post->ID
- get_the_ID()
- (no third parameter)

All of which are critical errors. It's not due to the post itself, if I take away the has_term() if statement, all of posts display. But I only want to show some that have a particular tag.

Comment: The third argument to [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) isn't a post type, it's a post ID. Its default is the current post.

Comment: Why are you passing `'posttypename'` as third parameter? If you pass anything at all (should not be necessary, when you are inside the loop), it needs to be a post id, or an actual WP_Post instance.

Comment: I've tried a few things as the third parameter; ($post->ID, get_the_id(), $post_id) and none have worked. I've tried removing the third param as well, all of these have resulted in a critical error.